# Azure- Substantial performance degradation when moving CreateTableIfNotExist()code from Run() to OnStart()

Tags: azure

I have a worker role which does some processing involving Azure storage. The overall performance gets degraded if I move CreateTableIfNotExist() code from workerrole’s Run() method to OnStart() method. For example it takes around 5-10 seconds to add an entry into azure storage in the case of CreateTableIfNotExist() code being added to OnStart(), whereas it takes only 200 milliseconds in the case of CreateTableIfNotExist() code being added to Run() method. There  is no other code changes.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't by accident move the CreateTableIfNotExists() method into the non-ending loop, did you?  CreateTableIfNotExists() is generally a slow call and should only be called very rarely (preferably once per application's)

Comment: No, I didn't. By the way in that case adding the same code in Run() would have shown the same behavior, isn't it? Below is the sample code I have used to test this behavior:           CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connStrTableStore);
CloudTableClient tableClient = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
tableClient.CreateTableIfNotExist("TestTable");